# Wrap native method with input parameter fixed size array

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a problem with wrapping methods on the C++ CLI, which have a fixed size array as input parameter.

This is the method I need to wrap:

```
BOOL SetNetworkMask(BYTE ucValue[4]);
```

What is a decent method to do this? Of all the possibilities, I tried this one, but It seems the most stupid:

```
bool RFDeviceWrap::SetNetworkMask(byte ucValue[4])
{
  return this->m_RFDevice->SetNetworkMask(ucValue[4]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All arrays degrade to pointers, so you can use this :

```
bool RFDeviceWrap::SetNetworkMask(byte * ucValue) {
    return this->m_RFDevice->SetNetworkMask(ucValue[4]);
}
```

Comment: but i need to call this method from c#. how can i do this?
I wrote in this way:
bool RFDeviceWrap::SetNetworkMask(byte *ucValue)
{
        return this->m_RFDevice->SetNerworkMask(&ucValue[4]);
}
will it work correctly?

Comment: It should, I don't know enough about cli.